# Sociality and meditation

Tags: meditation, buddha, tipitaka, doubt

I had a question.

I have been getting deeper into the Buddha's teaching and meditation & I feel awkward to be around or to talk to people, specifically those who do not meditate.

> How do I overcome this or is this OK?

Comment: This is actually a good sign. It means you are advancing. Everyone who makes spiritual advancement will no longer be interested in material life and will feel repulsive towards ordinary sinful materialistic people wh don't meditate.

Answer (score 1):

Talking to people, even if they are not meditators, shouldn't feel awkward if this talk has some meaning and is not mere chit-chat. Therefore, use conversation as another form of your practice, trying to be aware of what are you talking about, with what intention. Also, try to stay away of not so uncommon tendency among people who meditate to look upon to people who don't. This is another way of practice, developing compassion and understanding for all people, all beings, even when they behave differently. Since we are all in the same boat, we can't separate ourselves from them and we really shouldn't. Instead, just trying to look at them with more compassionate, more loving eyes. And sometimes that's not so easy. :)